# SELinux remove or leave the old SSH port label?

Tags: ssh, port, selinux

I am following [this (basic) security guide](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH#head-3579222198adaf43a3ecbdc438ebce74da40d8ec) to change my Server's SSH port to something else.

It says:

```
$ semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 2345 #Change me
```

...which would add a new label on top of port 2345 to say that this is relevant for SSH, and that the SSH process can access this port.

What bugs me, is that this does NOT remove the label on the old port 22.

**Is it safer to leave the old label in place, or is it safer to remove it?** I don't know if the default setting for ports are within confined or unconfined space, and I think this may matter.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but the command for removing the old port is:

```
# semanage port -d -p tcp 22
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no significant reason to remove the port type label from port 22 (nor is relocating your ssh server to another port necessarily going to make you more secure). If you do remove the label, then sshd will not be able to bind to port 22 and listen for connections.

Comment: Out of curiosity, you mentioned `(nor is relocating your ssh server to another port necessarily going to make you more secure)`. Why not? I would have thought that `For a hacker to determine ssh is running on your machine, he'll most likely scan port 22 to determine this. An effective method is to run ssh on a non-standard port.` would apply?

Comment: This only "protects" you from drive-by scanners who just try a large number of default usernames and passwords. Not allowing root logins with a password, and making sure you have strong passwords for all users, is sufficient there. Moving the port is not sufficient for a _targeted_ attack, as the attacker can find the new port number in a few seconds with a port scan.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What if you use port scan detection and block such attempts. (blacklisting ips that trying to get to undefined ports)?

Why it's not possible to run the following command `semanage port -d -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 22` and delete default port? I get error like this: `Port tcp/22 is defined in policy, cannot be deleted`

Comment: @MichaelHampton Did you find a way around this policy thing?

Comment: @Achilles You could add a port, but you cannot delete the default port from the SELinux policy.